# How to request a specific size of profile photo from Office 365 Graph API?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

According to the online documentation (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/profilephoto) I should be able to make the following request:

```
GET /me/photo/<size>
```

Where **size** is described as:

> The supported sizes of HD photos on Exchange Online are as follows: '48x48', '64x64', '96x96', '120x120', '240x240', '360x360','432x432', '504x504', and '648x648'.

However, none of the following requests work - they all return an error:

```
GET /me/photo/48x48
GET /me/photo/48
GET /me/photo/'48x48'
```

It would have been useful to have some example requests available as part of the documentation.

Anyone able to advise on the correct query format? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the following format is used to request different sized images. It's only working on the beta endpoint right now.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photos('48x48')/$value`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photos('360x360')/$value`

I'll submit a bug so the documentation is updated.

Thanks!
-Dan

Edit:
Actually, the following is also accepted on the beta endpoint.
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/Photos/48X48/$value`